# Reshaping wide to long with every n columns

Tags: r, dplyr, transpose

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```r
dw <- read.table(header=T, text='
 ID     q1    q2   q3     q4     q5    ...q10  
   A   10    6     50     10      bA   
   B   12    5     70     11      bB
   C   20    7     20     8       bC
   D   22    8     22     9       bD
 ')
```

I would like to move every 2 columns after `'ID'` to new rows so it looks like:

```
   ID  q1   q2 
   A   10    6     
   B   12    5     
   C   20    7     
   D   22    8 
   A   50    10
   B   70   11
   C   20   8
   D   22   9
   ....
```

`pivot_longer` seems to move every single column instead of multiple columns?

Comment: What happens to the other columns (`q5` to `q10`)?

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `df %>% select(ID:q2) %>% bind_rows(df %>% select(ID, q1 = q3, q2 = q4))` could be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not concerned with the column names (other than `ID`), and that they are all the same class. For this, we can "pivot" manually, without the safeguards or power of `pivot_lower` perhaps, but without the requirements as well.

The first step is to make sure that `class` won't be an issue; because you have some strings in there, we need to convert all to `character`:

```r
dw[-1] <- lapply(dw[-1], as.character)
```

After that, we can manually extract every two (non-`ID`) columns and combine with `ID`:

```r
cols <- seq_along(dw)[-1]
list_of_frames <- lapply(split(cols, cols %/% 2), function(ind) setNames(dw[,c(1, ind)], c("ID", "q1", "q2")))
list_of_frames
# $`1`
#   ID q1 q2
# 1  A 10  6
# 2  B 12  5
# 3  C 20  7
# 4  D 22  8
# $`2`
#   ID q1 q2
# 1  A 50 10
# 2  B 70 11
# 3  C 20  8
# 4  D 22  9
# $`3`
#   ID q1 q2
# 1  A bA zA
# 2  B bB zB
# 3  C bC zC
# 4  D bD zD
```

This can be easily combined with several methods, choose one of:

```r
data.table::rbindlist(list_of_frames)
dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_frames)
do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)
#    ID q1 q2
# 1   A 10  6
# 2   B 12  5
# 3   C 20  7
# 4   D 22  8
# 5   A 50 10
# 6   B 70 11
# 7   C 20  8
# 8   D 22  9
# 9   A bA zA
# 10  B bB zB
# 11  C bC zC
# 12  D bD zD
```

---

Data

```r
dw <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), q1 = c("10", "12", "20", "22"), q2 = c("6", "5", "7", "8"), q3 = c("50", "70", "20", "22"), q4 = c("10", "11", "8", "9"), q5 = c("bA", "bB", "bC", "bD"), q6 = c("zA", "zB", "zC", "zD")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks! But I got this error "Error in cols%/%2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: Oops, fixed, please try again. (Edited, only change is `cols <- seq_along(dw)[-1]`)

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
data.frame(ID = dw$ID,
           q1 = unlist(dw[,seq(2, ncol(dw), 2)], use.names = FALSE),
           q2 = unlist(dw[,seq(3, ncol(dw), 2)], use.names = FALSE))
```

With data:

```
dw <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     q1 = c(10L, 12L, 20L, 22L),
                     q2 = c(6L, 5L, 7L, 8L),
                     q3 = c(50L, 70L, 20L, 22L),
                     q4 = c(10L, 11L, 8L, 9L),
                     q5 = c("bA", "bB", "bC", "bD"),
                     q6 = c("cc", "dd", "ee", "ff"))
                , class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

data.frame(ID = dw$ID,
           q1 = unlist(dw[,seq(2, ncol(dw), 2)], use.names = FALSE),
           q2 = unlist(dw[,seq(3, ncol(dw), 2)], use.names = FALSE))
#>    ID q1 q2
#> 1   A 10  6
#> 2   B 12  5
#> 3   C 20  7
#> 4   D 22  8
#> 5   A 50 10
#> 6   B 70 11
#> 7   C 20  8
#> 8   D 22  9
#> 9   A bA cc
#> 10  B bB dd
#> 11  C bC ee
#> 12  D bD ff
```

Or more generally:

```
n <- 3L # operate on every 3 columns
data.frame(
  setNames(
    c(
      list(dw[,1]),
      lapply(
        2:(n + 1L),
        function(i) unlist(dw[,seq(i, ncol(dw), n)], TRUE, FALSE)
      )
    ),
    names(dw)[1:(n + 1L)]
  )
)

#>   ID q1 q2 q3
#> 1  A 10  6 50
#> 2  B 12  5 70
#> 3  C 20  7 20
#> 4  D 22  8 22
#> 5  A 10 bA cc
#> 6  B 11 bB dd
#> 7  C  8 bC ee
#> 8  D  9 bD ff
```

Answer (score 1):

The `melt(...)` method for `data.table` allows for melting groups of columns. Using `dw` from @r2evans answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dw)
result <- melt(dw, measure.vars = list(seq(2, ncol(dw), 2), seq(3, ncol(dw), 2)))
result[, variable:=NULL]
result
##     ID value1 value2
##  1:  A     10      6
##  2:  B     12      5
##  3:  C     20      7
##  4:  D     22      8
##  5:  A     50     10
##  6:  B     70     11
##  7:  C     20      8
##  8:  D     22      9
##  9:  A     bA     zA
## 10:  B     bB     zB
## 11:  C     bC     zC
## 12:  D     bD     zD
```

`melt(...)` introduces a column `variable` which keeps track of the location of the original columns in the wide dataset. You don't seem to care about that so it's removed. If there are indeed different classes (integer, character) `melt(...)` will take care of that with a warning.